# Using a C# library (dll) class from c executable hangs on the GSHandle (^)

Tags: c#, c++, c, .net-4.0, garbage-collection

OK before you say I can’t do it, lets talk about what I can do….
I can call a C# library from a C++ executable. (have done it on this project)
I can call a C++ library from C. (That should not be a surprise)

So having the three chained up with the C++ code calling a C# library and the C code calling the same C++ library the c execution thread chokes/crashes on the GSHandle(^). Has anyone seen this? Besides attempting to jump the grand canyon, is there something that I have missed that will keep this from ever working?

My code?... Hmm running the C++ library from C# works. Running the c++ library from c works if I remove all references using my c# class and the GCHandle(^).  I will save the culling of the code for presenting it here, until I am even more frustrated… For now, lets say that the c++ is based on the checked answer here: [How to call a C# library from Native C++ (using C++\CLI and IJW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293888/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-library-from-c-using-c-cli-and-ijw/13823687#13823687)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten it to work now. I cant say definitively but I suspect that it was one of three possibilities.

1) The C code was choking on the class that I was trying to use from C code. I entirely removed the class structure from my c wrapper and used only functions. (Clearly I have been away from c for too long.)

2) The code was throwing a linker error when built in the company build environment.

3) the code assemblies were not being found for the library.

The truth is that all three were going wrong with my code, and anyone of them could have been a cause for the crash.