# C# Method cannot be invoked in c++ wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, java-native-interface

I want to use my c# dll in a java project. Now I need to create a wrapper library for my c# code.

My C#-Method has this signature

```
    public static String scanFile(String path)
```

now how can I call this from my wrapper c++ class?

```
String scanFile(const System::String path){
    return CardScan32::Scanner::scanFile(path);
}
```

Currently I try this but its not working, because it cannot be called with this argument list

Comment: you might fin this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293888/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-library-from-native-c-using-c-cli-and-ijw) discussion useful

Answer (score 0):

You should use `System::String^ path` in your c++ cli wrapper. You should remove the `const` too.

Comment: Tried this already but error occurs that scanFile cannot be called with the given arguments

Comment: translate from german: 
ÍntelliSense: no custom convert from " "System::String ^"" in ""System::String"" exists

Comment: is this error from my code? if yes what error do you get from your own code?