# Using C# code in C++ (COM) Dll import not working quite right

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com

As the title implies, I am having difficulty calling C# code from C++. A bit of context: there is an API call in C# (that does not exist in the C++ version of the API) and I need to integrate it into a much larger C++ project.

I have been reading over [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293888/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-library-from-native-c-using-c-cli-and-ijw?newreg=c875a4d0cf1c4e10b14dbaf11a190786), and made the most headway with the COM method.

My C# dll compiles*. After copying the resulting dll and tlb files into the appropriate C++ project directory, I open an admin cmd prompt in the same C++ project directory and run:

```
regasm MyFirstDll.dll /codebase /tlb
```

(*I compile it as a Class Library, Assembly name: MyFirstDll, Default namespace: MyMethods, Assembly Information... -> Make assembly Com-Visible is checked, Build->Register for COM interop is also checked.)

Using the Object Browser, I am able to see the class I defined, as well as a method with the appropriate args and signature. 
[Screenshot of it showing up in Object Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnRBx.jpg)

The issue I am experiencing is with the method call (and not the class). Even though the method is visible in the Object Browser, in my code it is not recognized as a method of the object.

class "ATL::_NoAddRefReleaseOnCComPtr" has no member "Add"
Here is my code:

MyFirstDll C# Project:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//

namespace MyMethods
{
    // Interface declaration.
    [Guid("8a0f4457-b08f-4124-bc49-18fe11cb108e")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface Easy_Math
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        long Add(long i, long j);
    };
}
namespace MyMethods
{
    [Guid("0cb5e240-0df8-4a13-87dc-50823a395ec1")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("MyMethods.AddClass")]
    public class AddClass: Easy_Math
    {
        public AddClass() { }
        [ComVisible(true)]

        public long Add(long i, long j)
        {
            return (i + j);
        }
    }
}
```

NateMath.h:

```
#include <atlcomcli.h> 
#import "MyFirstDll.tlb"

class NateMath
{
public:
    NateMath(void);
    ~NateMath(void);
    long Add(long a, long b);

private:
    CComPtr<MyFirstDll::AddClass> adder;
};
```

NateMath.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <atlcomcli.h>
#import "MyFirstDll.tlb"
#include "NateMath.h"

NateMath::NateMath(void)
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    adder.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MyFirstDll::AddClass));
}

NateMath::~NateMath(void)
{
    CoUninitialize();
}
long NateMath::Add(long a, long b) {
    return adder->Add(a,b);
}
```

The issue being that in "return adder->Add(a,b)" (NateMath.cpp) Add(a,b) shows up red with class "ATL::_NoAddRefReleaseOnCComPtr" has no member "Add"

Comment: Try using a `CComPtr<MyFirstDll::Easy_Math>` instead of a `CComPtr<MyFirstDll::AddClass>`.

Comment: @HansPassant That is good to know! Unfortunately after updating the C# AddClass.Add code to int Add(int i, int j), the same error still appears. :(

Comment: @MichaelGunter If I use a CComPtr to the interface instead of the class, how will it know to call my class's implementation of the method?

Comment: Because you `CoCreateInstance` on the UUID of `AddClass`, but with COM, you always call methods of a class through one of its implemented interfaces.

Comment: Ok great! Any idea why I'd get a null pointer exception when trying to call Add on an instance of the C++ object? NateMath nm = NateMath(); long x = nm.Add(1,2); Throws read access violation, "nm.adder.p was nullptr."

Comment: Did you check the return value of CoCreateInstance?

Comment: Looks like it needs to be registered. (HRESULT 0x80040154). If you have tips on that I'd gladly accept them, however if not at least now I have something to go off of. Would you like to post your comments as an answer so I can accept them?

Comment: You need to use `regasm.exe` to register the C# assembly, or set up your C# project to automatically register it when it builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to use your class name in `CComPtr` instead of the interface. With COM, all methods are defined on an interface, not on the class that implements an interfaces.

You can `CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(YourClass))` because the intent is to create an instance of `YourClass` (which is identified by the GUID expressed by `__uuidof(YourClass)`).  However, `YourClass` in the C++ is a dummy struct that's only present so that you can read the uuid -- the definition of `YourClass` in the C++ generated from the `#import` is empty and will always be empty.

To fix this, use `CComPtr<YourInterface>`. This tells the C++ that you want to communicate with the referenced object via that interface. Here's a rule to remember: The type argument to `CComPtr` and `CComQIPtr` must *always* be a COM interface. That COM interface can either be an explicitly-defined interface, or it can be the "class interface" which was automatically produced by .NET.

Speaking of class interfaces: If you had used `ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual` instead of `None`, you could have used a `CComPtr<_YourClass>` (note the leading underscore -- `_YourClass` is the class interface, whereas `YourClass` would be the class. I would recommend doing it the way you already have, however.

Comment: That is not correct, he did it right by declaring the interface explicitly.  He just forgot to use it.  Good advice probably ought to include the recommendation to use the smart pointer type that #import auto-generates, ought to be named `Easy_MathPtr` in this case.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, thanks. I forgot that the class interface is `_YourClass`, not `YourClass`. As far as using `CComPtr` vs `_com_ptr`, that's entirely up to the consuming developer. If they're consuming this in an existing ATL project, there no reason to prefer the generated `_com_ptr` over `CComPtr`. In fact, doing so would mean you have an extra exception type to deal with (`_com_error`).