# Why can't my native .DLL project find my .NET .dll?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I have followed the instructions provided by Smoke here: [How to call a C# library from Native C++ (using C++\CLI and IJW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293888/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-library-from-native-c-using-c-cli-and-ijw)

I also made sure to add the .dll path to the additional #using directories of the native C++ project in visual studio. I also added #using  to the wrapper .cpp file. All .cpp files have cli enabled, and I have enabled COM on the C# project (but I'm not using COM so that shouldn't matter).

I have also added the C# .dll to the execution path of the C++ .dll.

I am still getting System:IO:FileNotFoundException while debugging. Everything compiles fine, so Visual Studio has found the C# .dll, but my C++ .dll isn't finding it at runtime.

The full exception:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why?

**EDIT:**

I figured it out. I didn't realize that the C# .dll needs to be in the same folder as the application that loads the C++ .dll, not in the same folder as the C++ .dll.

Comment: What exactly is the full exception?

Comment: Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/QNZfS

Comment: Check the bin directory to make sure both DLLs have been copied. Also don't compile for AnyCPU, use x64, as C++ does not support AnyCPU.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. All .dll's have been copied to the same location. I am compiling for x86.

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't realize that the C# .dll needs to be in the same folder as the **application** that loads the C++ .dll, not in the same folder as the C++ .dll.

Comment: @DustyEngineer - If you figured it out submit an answer to your question.  The solution to your question should not exist in the question itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't realize that the C# .dll needs to be in the same folder as the application that loads the C++ .dll, not in the same folder as the C++ .dll.