# C# DllExport functions not showing in DLL export table after compilation

Tags: c#, dllexport

I have a C# library I am exporting as an extension for a C++ program. I am using the [unmanagedexports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) package to export the functions.

***Question Update:***
So initially I thought I needed a .def file to accompany my C# dll when it was being imported by the C++ application however after Martheen's comment it seems my dll has no exported functions at all. I am assuming this after the tools [MakeDef](https://www.codeguru.com/tools/standalonetools/article.php/c1351/MakeDef--Intelligent-DEF-file-Generator-for-Win32-Apps.htm) and [DLL Export Viewer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) both showed the dll as having no exports.

Code I am using is below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace TestExtension
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public static AppDomain TestDomain;

        [DllExport("TestFunc")]
        public static void TestFunc(ExtensionClient client, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string args)
        {
            client.Print("TestOutput");
        }
    }
}
```

***The rest of the original question:***
*The program I am loading them into says it needs a .def file in the documentation. I understand this file is created by C++ programs and documents the exported functionality of a dll. My C# project creates a .pdb file which I understand does a similar thing however it's not in a human readable format and just changing the extension to .def didn't seem to work.*

*So my question is can I create a .def file for my C# dll or is there another suitable workaround/solution to this problem?*

Comment: Have you tried https://www.codeguru.com/tools/standalonetools/article.php/c1351/MakeDef--Intelligent-DEF-file-Generator-for-Win32-Apps.htm ?

Comment: I have not tried it but I will and I will update with results.

Comment: So it seems I have a worse problem than I thought I did. Using MakeDef I got a fatal error stating it could not read the export table and after running a tool called DLL Export Viewer I found after some quick googling that could also not read the export table. As such I shall update the question to reflect this. Thank you for helping it is very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't recall anything actually needing a .def file in 32 bit windows. What you probably want is an import library. GCC ships with a tool to make import libraries from dlls.

Comment: `using RGiesecke.DllExport;` That hasn't been updated in a really long time. Why not use COM interop, instead, which is the recommended and supported way for unmanaged code to use .NET assemblies? Or use C++/CLI on the other side and communicate directly.

Comment: I was using it mainly because the examples I saw were using it. If you have any guides on using COM interop that cover a situation like this I would be really interested to see them.

Comment: See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016935) and the other links on that page.